# Error while installing Microsoft Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, installation

I am using windows 7 32bit 
I can install Microsoft Visual studio 2008 and Microsoft Visual studio 2012 on my system but when I want to instal Microsoft Visual studio 2010  It errors like this :

this is error log  [dd_error_vs_vstscore_100.txt](http://panahit.ir/upload/dd_error_vs_vstscore_100.txt) :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following volumes do not have enough disk space for the installation:

Check your log file it says no enough space change the drive or allocate more memory to your boot drive